# Cross Compiling Expect for ARM

Tags: linux, arm, cross-compiling, embedded-linux, expect

I have downloaded [expect5.4](http://sourceforge.net/projects/expect/) . I'm trying to cross compile it for ARM(PandaBoard) running stripped down version of linux.

In the initial setup of configuring , I try

```
Shell$ ./configure --host=ARM
configure: WARNING: If you wanted to set the --build type, don't use --host.
    If a cross compiler is detected then cross compile mode will be used.
checking for correct TEA configuration... ok (TEA 3.9)
configure: configuring expect 5.45
checking for Tcl configuration... found /home/user1/scripts/tcl8.6.0/unix/tclConfig.sh
checking for existence of /home/user1/scripts/tcl8.6.0/unix/tclConfig.sh... loading
configure: --prefix defaulting to TCL_PREFIX /usr/local
configure: --exec-prefix defaulting to TCL_EXEC_PREFIX /usr/local
checking for ARM-gcc... /home/user1/toolchain/toolchain/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... yes
checking for suffix of executables...
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether /home/user1/toolchain/toolchain/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for /home/user1/toolchain/toolchain/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc option to accept ANSI C... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... /home/user1/toolchain/toolchain/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -E
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for ARM-ranlib... no
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for egrep... grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
..
.. 
..
..
..
checking for openpty... no
checking for openpty in -lutil... yes
checking if running Sequent running SVR4... no
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... Invalid configuration `ARM': machine `ARM' not recognized
configure: error: /bin/bash tclconfig/config.sub ARM failed
```

**UPDATE:**
On compiling with ./configure --host=arm , It goes further the error i'm getting now is

```
checking for sysconf... yes
checking for strftime... yes
checking for strchr... yes
checking for timezone... yes
checking for siglongjmp... yes
checking for memcpy... yes
checking if WNOHANG requires _POSIX_SOURCE... configure: error: Expect can't be cross compiled
```

Its able to pick arm-gcc but it fails for some reason.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to cross compile Expect for ARM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12921606/how-to-cross-compile-expect-for-arm)

Answer (score 1):

You will get a bit further with `--host=arm` (lowercase), but not
much: expect just doesn't want to be cross-compiled. Overcoming this
would require non-trivial modifications in `configure.in`. It could be
rational to work on them if `expect` is the only thing you want to
cross-compile, but if there are many others, you'd better setup some
environment where you can run compiled binaries ([scratchbox](http://www.scratchbox.org) or
something like that).

Comment: your link won't load for me (timeouts or something)

Comment: well, scratchbox site is down for now. The link is correct, so it might become useful later. There is enough information about scratchbox around the Internet, maybe it's even the part of your Linux distribution (it is available in Debian repository, for example)

Comment: @Anton, Thanks for the suggestion. As of now i have to cross compile only expect,I hope that will have tcl libraries built in.Can you pls help me with those modifications to configure.in

Comment: You should have TCL already cross-compiled to be able to compile expect; its source code archive does not include Tcl, nor is it built automatically when you build expect. (Fortunately, tcl *does* support cross-compilation quite well). As of expect's `configure.in`, just post new questions when you're stuck with something.

Answer (score 0):

`Expect` (Version = 5.45.4) is available in [buildroot 2019.11](https://buildroot.org/) and it has support for the PandaBoard.

You could

1. download `buildroot 2019.11' from the project .
2. Extract it
3. run `make pandaboard_defconfig` inside the `buildroot-folder`
4. run `make menuconfig` and enable `TCL`(-> Target packages
   -> Interpreter languages and scripting) and then `expect` (-> Target packages
   -> Interpreter languages and scripting) because of the dependency
5. run `make` to build the whole thing and get the executable from the
   `output/build/expect` folder